# HTTPS for server IP address shows as invalid certificate

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate, https, ip-address

I have a website, say www.foo.com with an IP address 1.2.3.4 I have an SSL certificate for www.foo.com and when I visit https://www.foo.com all is good. However if I visit https://1.2.3.4 it says the certificate is invalid, which is fair enough.
Is there any way to get https://1.2.3.4 to redirect to https://www.foo.com using apache2 or am I stuck with it having a certificate error?

Comment: The warning is correct. Yes you can redirect your site. And yes it is also possible with Apache.

Comment: How many people are likely to be visiting you by IP?

Comment: None that I know of, I was just trying to cover all bases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't redirect **https** without first getting the "Invalid Certificate" error if the certificate doesn't match to domain name used (in this case it's the IP 1.2.3.4 since it is manually entered).

You can redirect **http**://1.2.3.4 without this problem because there is no SSL handshake.  But if you specify **https** this requires the use of SSL which in turn returns the "Invalid Certificate" error as there is no way to validate the SSL handshake.

Comment: The certificate does exist for the domain, just not for the IP address. So if someone visits https://1.2.3.4 I am stuck with them seeing the invalid certificate error?

Comment: Yes, pretty much.

Comment: Correct: the SSL handshake -- where the certificate verification happens -- takes place before anything else.  So you can't redirect away without that warning, since the handshake happens before HTTP starts.